# creating a random password using python and ascii value

Tags: python

I wanted to create a program that tells you a random password and check the validity of the password
I created a random value from 33-126(this are the ascii value that gives output from the keyboard) and then append it to the password and check the validity. but it was doing time-out and no output is given.
when I debug it then I saw that it was randomly stopping at a random point. the password was in list form to make my work easier. I checked the validity of the password the list (password) was eg- `password = ['2', 'f', 'W', '@', '/']`

You can see that password[0] is '2' not 2 so I had created to check `int type` so it was stuck there

````
def makePassword():
    password = []
    for _ in range(1, random.randint(5, 21)):
        rm = random.randint(33, 126)
        ascii_value = chr(rm)
        password.append(ascii_value)
    return password


def isalnum(password):
    password = list(password)
    index = random.randint(0, len(password))
    skw = chr(random.choice([random.randint(48, 57), random.randint(65, 90), random.randint(97, 122)]))
    for i in password:
        if not i.isalnum():
            password.insert(index, skw)
    return password


def isalpha(password):
    password = list(password)
    index = random.randint(0, len(password))
    skw = chr(random.choice([random.randint(65, 90), random.randint(97, 122)]))
    for i in password:
        if not i.isalpha():
            password.insert(index, skw)
    return password


def isdigit(password):
    password = list(password)
    index = random.randint(0, len(password))
    skw = chr(random.randint(48, 57))
    for i in password:
        if not i.isdigit():
            password.insert(index, skw)
    return password


def isupper(password):
    password = list(password)
    index = random.randint(0, len(password))
    skw = chr(random.randint(65, 90))
    for i in password:
        if not i.isupper():
            password.insert(index, skw)
    return password


def islower(password):
    password = list(password)
    index = random.randint(0, len(password))
    skw = chr(random.randint(97, 122))
    for i in password:
        if not i.isalnum():
            password.insert(index, skw)
    return password


word = makePassword()
for i in word:
    if not i.isalnum():
        word = isalnum(word)
    if not i.isalpha():
        word = isalpha(word)
    if not i.isdigit():
        word = isdigit(word)
    if not i.isupper():
        word = isupper(word)
    if not i.lower():
        word = islower(word)
print(word)```
````

Comment: yes, when i run the code it create a random password and check its validity like it has an uppercase letter a symbol a number like this

Comment: yes but that not for i am making it for

Comment: I am a beginner  so can you tell me where do you live bro

Comment: I mean which country